# Add category labels to center of Population Pyramid

Tags: highcharts

Having a look at converting some legacy charts over to Highcharts, and no problem doing a population pyramid, but if I wanted to add the age categories as boxes in the center of the chart and disable the y-axis, any ideas? I don't know if I would need to use a custom positioning function maybe?

https://jsfiddle.net/w8qov1te/1/

```
var categories = ['0-4', '5-9', '10-14', '15-19',
            '20-24', '25-29', '30-34', '35-39', '40-44',
            '45-49', '50-54', '55-59', '60-64', '65-69',
            '70-74', '75-79', '80-84', '85-89', '90-94',
            '95-99', '100 + '];
  
  Highcharts.chart('container', {
        chart: {
            type: 'bar',
            marginRight:110,
            marginLeft:110
            
        },
        title: {
            text: 'Population Pyramid, Census '
        },
  plotOptions: {
            series: {
                stacking: 'normal',
        dataLabels: {
            enabled: true,
            inside: true
        }
    }
 },
        subtitle: {
            enabled:false
        },
        xAxis: [{
            categories: categories,
            reversed: false,
            labels: {
                step: 1
            }
        }, { // mirror axis on right side
            opposite: true,
            reversed: false,
            categories: categories,
            linkedTo: 0,
            labels: {
                step: 1
            }
        }],
        yAxis: {
            title: {
                text: null
            },
            labels: {
                formatter: function () {
                    return Math.abs(this.value);
                }
            }
        },

    
        tooltip: {
            shadow:false,
            formatter: function () {
                return '<b>' + this.series.name + ', age ' + this.point.category + '</b><br/>' +
                    'Population: ' + Highcharts.numberFormat(Math.abs(this.point.y), 0);
            }
        },

        series: [{
  dataLabels: [{
        align: 'center',
        format: '({y})'
    }
    ],
            name: 'Male',
            data: [9765,11755,13535,13275,13560,12610,13515,14210,14780,16485,18685,20530,20695,19720,16600,10585,5960,2835,985]
        }, {
            name: 'Female',
            data:[-9220,-11275,-12640,-12445,-12520,-12435,-14010,-15235,-16115,-17510,-19690,-21620,-21825,-20730,-17805,-11780,-7275,-3910,-2425]
        }]
        });
```

Comment: I made some attempts by adjusting the axis labels, but would need to set those to be centered in general if we made the chart responsive. Will keep digging!

[link](https://jsfiddle.net/n67bwqga/)

Comment: Hi @jdower27, I am not sure how your design should look exactly, but please check this live example: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/by1hnsc2/ with centred labels.

Comment: Hi @ppotaczek, I think that's getting there.. an unexpected side note, setting a wider label worked by setting the width in label style and then using the HTML as well. 

      style:{
                width:'200px',step: 1
      },

Comment: Great! Please don't hesitate to ask in case of any further questions.